# How to make Visual Studio forget a namespace?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I have a project called Geometry inside of which I had created a folder, and had been referencing that folder by its namespace, "project".Geometry.

I decided that I would rather simply name a class Geometry instead of the entire folder, so I moved all of the classes inside of the folder up a level.

When I named my new class "Geometry" I still get:

> namespace "" already contains definition for "Geometry"

How can I make Visual Studio forget about that namespace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do more than just move the classes up a level from that folder. You must go into each of them and change the namespace associated with it.

code like this probably still exists in those classes:

```
namespace projectnamespace.Geometry
{
   ...
}
```